# How to let user choose which table needs to be updated Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form in my website, which is the same for three tables (Homework, Class, Random)
So basically I want to make a ChoiceField on the top of the form, to let user choose where to upload file.

I was thinking, because these tables have common abstract class, may be I can choose it from there somehow. But can not figure out how.

Or may be there is much better solution for this.

just in case this is my code:

```
#models.py
class FileDescription(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True;
        ordering = ['file_creation_time']

    subject = models.ForeignKey('Subjects', null=True, blank=True, primary_key=True)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file_uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file_description = models.TextField()
    file_creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.file_name)

#template
<ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#homework">Homework</a></li>
        <li><a href="#class-papers">Class Papers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#random-papers">Random Papers</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="homework" class="tab-section">
        <h2>Homework</h2>
        <p>This section contains Homework</p>

            {% if homework_files %}
                <ul>
                    {% for file in homework_files %}
                        <li>{{ file.file_name }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
    </div>

#forms.py
class Homework_Content_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Homework_Content
        exclude=('subject', 
                 'subject_name',
                 'file_creation_time',
                 'file_uploaded_by',
                 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: Separate Forms**

```
class GenericContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         exclude = ('subject', 'subject_name', 'file_creation_time', 'file_uploaded_by')

     TYPE_CHOICES = (
         ('homework', 'Homework'),
         ('class', 'Class Paper'),
         ('random', 'Random Paper'),
     )

     type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

class HomeworkForm(GenericContentForm):
     class Meta(GenericContentForm.Meta):
         model = Homework

class ClassPaperForm(GenericContentForm):
     class Meta(GenericContentForm.Meta):
         model = ClassPaper

class RandomPaperForm(GenericContentForm):
     class Meta(GenericContentForm.Meta):
         model = RandomPaper
```

Then in your view you just pick one to start with, and when you have the POST data, you can instantiate a different one instead:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        type = request.POST.get('type')
        if type == 'homework':
            form = HomeworkForm(request.POST)
        elif type == 'class':
            form = ClassPaperForm(request.POST)
        elif type == 'random':
            form = RandomPaperForm(request.POST)

    else:
        form = HomeworkForm()

    ...
```

**Method 2: Use Proxy Models**

Since these three models all share the same data, having three separate tables is redundant. Instead of `FileDescription` being abstract, make it just a normal standard model, and add a field to it for type, with choices of "Homework", "Class Paper" and "Random Paper". Then create proxy models for each:

```
class HomeworkManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(HomeworkManager, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)
        return qs.filter(type='homework')

class Homework(FileDescription):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = HomeworkManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.type = 'homework'
        super(Homework, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, you just need one form for `FileDescription` and when the user's choice for the "type" will be saved. You can then access anything set as type "homework" with the standard `Homework.objects.all()`.